# Memory allocation increasing in instruments xcode

Tags: ios, memory-management

[image]

In my iOS app memory usage keep increasing. App syncs data with remote server. When it requesting data memory usage increase by nearly 15MB per every 3 mins. I don't know how to track allocated objects. I am using ARC. How to overcome this issue.

Edit - [image]

[image]

Sometimes these screenshots may help to solve this issue.

Comment: allocated memory not released, how you are adding your new views?

Comment: Overriding a dealloc method and setting a breakpoint to it might help you find the objects not deallocated. If you are not putting them in some kind of array this is most likely a cross reference issue: Object A has a reference to object B while B has a reference to object A. If this is done with properties you need to use (weak) on one of the two properties.

Comment: I am using ARC then there are no dealloc methods?